# C print ping-pong using semaphores and threads

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I am not sure I understand semaphores and threads so I decided to try a relatively simple example. I am trying to have 2 threads that will alternate printing, one printing "ping" the other printing "pong" each notifying the other that it is done by use of a semaphore. But when I implement the code below, it prints ping several hundred times followed by pong several hundred times with a slight pause.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
sem_t pingsem;

void ping(){
    printf("Ping started\n");
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("ping\n");
        sem_post(&pingsem);
    }
}

void pong(){
    printf("Pong started\n");
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("pong\n");
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&pingsem);
    }
}

int main(){
    sem_destroy(&pingsem);  //make sure the semaphore starts dead
    sem_init(&pingsem, 0, 1);  //initialize semaphore
    pthread_t ping_thread, pong_thread;  //start the threading
    pthread_create(&ping_thread, NULL, ping, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pong_thread, NULL, pong, NULL);
    pthread_join(ping_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(pong_thread,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile using:

gcc stest.c -o stest -lpthread -lrt

with no errors or warnings, but when I run it I get:

```
$ ./stest
Ping started
ping
ping
ping
ping
Pong started
ping
ping
.
. hundreds of pings
.
ping
ping
ping
pong
pong
pong
pong
.
. hundreds of pongs
.
```

It will eventually switch off but why are the threads not alternating printing every other one?

Comment: Why do you think your code forces them to alternate? After `ping` has been printed, what do you think stops it from being printed again?

Comment: Calling `sem_destroy` on an uninitialized semaphore is [undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sem_destroy.html).

Comment: Now that I re-read the code with the solutions below in mind, I don't know why I would expect them to alternate, it will wait and post to within the same loop, there is nothing stopping it. I had thought that the wait would make it stop, but since the last iteration posted, it doesn't wait.

Comment: @pilcrow, I ran into an issue on another problem where if a semaphore ended in deadlock, the next time it was run new semaphore would not initialize correctly unless it was first destroyed. I'm not entirely sure why, but this fixed that problem.

Comment: Your code is very close to working, you just need to use two semaphores as Martin James pointed out in a comment below and I discovered while searching for classic examples of the ping-pong case. I've provided a working example in an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you create a thread it will execute as soon as the OS says it can!
So you created two threads like so:

```
pthread_create(&ping_thread, NULL, ping, NULL);
// scheduler interrupt from OS
pthread_create(&pong_thread, NULL, pong, NULL);
```

Which was fine, but the OS saw the first new thread and ran it until its timeslice was exhausted. Only then did the main thread get back control long enough to create the next thread.

As for why they're not alternating is a different issue! You see how difficult thread synchronization can be? You have this code:

```
while(1){
    sem_wait(&pingsem);
    printf("ping\n");
    sem_post(&pingsem);
}
```

But you initialized the semaphore to the value of 1. So sem_wait decrements to 0, then prints a message, then increments back to 1. No problem, right?

Well the delay between the sem_post and the subsequent(next loop) sem_wait is only 1 instruction, a jump back to the beginning of the loop. So unless, by chance, the OS interrupts the thread after the sem_post, but before the sem_wait, the single thread will continue printing on its own.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to use mutexes! There are a few relevant functions: pthread_mutex_lock, pthread_mutex_trylock, and pthread_mutex_unlock. Figuring out how this helps is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: As pointed out above, lots of POSIX functions are triggers to the OS to relinquish control of the current thread. For example, almost all IO will give control back to the OS. An explicit syscall exists(atleast on Linux) sched_yield(). But make sure that GCC doesn't optimize it out!

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I expected this code to alternate printing every time.

Comment: @JameTSmith The solution you recommended doesn't answer the question - in the sense that the poster wanted to learn and resolve the problem with semaphores, and it is possible with a small tweak to the questioner's code example.

Answer (score 7):

The problem shown in your example is, it's a race because neither read effectively blocks the other. Both threads run as the scheduler allows. The way it's coded, each thread can free-run (loop) multiple times during its time slice, and satisfies its own semaphore test. On a multi-core/multi-CPU system with a typical schedule, both threads can both run simultaneously and step all over each other somewhat arbitrarily.

Here's a working ping-ponging threads example that uses complimentary semaphores to create the ping-pong interlock you want.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

sem_t pingsem, pongsem;

void *
ping(void *arg) 
{
    for (;;) {
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("ping\n");
        sem_post(&pongsem);
    }
}

void *
pong(void *arg) 
{
    for (;;) {
        sem_wait(&pongsem);
        printf("pong\n");
        sem_post(&pingsem);
    }
}

int 
main(void) 
{
    sem_init(&pingsem, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&pongsem, 0, 1);
    pthread_t ping_thread, pong_thread; 
    pthread_create(&ping_thread, NULL, ping, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pong_thread, NULL, pong, NULL);
    pthread_join(ping_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(pong_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used this example to compare the same program written in go (Exercise 9-5 in the Go Programming Language, Donovan and Kernighan) . I modified it slightly (I removed the printfs and limited the loops to 1000000.) The go ping pong ran about 10 times faster. So go’s go threads are lighter and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need two semaphores, 'pingsem' and 'pongsem', say.  Initialize one to 1 and the other to zero. Then:

ping_thread:

```
while(true){
  wait(pingsem);
  doWork();
  send(pongsem);
}
```

pong_thread:

```
while(true){
  wait(pongsem);
  doWork();
  send(pingsem);
}
```

The one unit that was initialized into one semaphore then acts as a work token and is signaled back-and-forth between the threads.  Only the thread with the token can do the work, the other has to wait until it gets the token.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is posted after I provided a cleanly compiled, tested, simple, self-explanatory, working example.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2 me neither.  I either just did not see it or thought it was another of those horrible sleep/yield things.  Anyway, I upvoted your answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

James T. Smith has the right answer.. that since you didn't schedule out before grabbing your lock again, you would expect just about every time it would be able to re-grab the lock before the thread finished it's time slice.

If you want to force scheduling out so that the other one can run, you can try sleep(0) or sched_yield(). This will force a scheduling out so that if another thread was waiting to run it would. This would be more likely to see your ping,pong,ping,pong. But still not a guarantee and completely dependent on your OS scheduler (and probably only works on a single core system with both threads at the same priority).

Try this: (like I said.. no guarantees.. but a good possibility it will work)

```
void ping(){
    printf("Ping started\n");
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("ping\n");
        sem_post(&pingsem);
        sched_yield(); // Schedule out.
    }
}

void pong(){
    printf("Pong started\n");
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("pong\n");
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&pingsem);
        sched_yield(); // Schedule out.
    }
}
```

edit: changed to sched_yield()

Comment: On Linux the sched_yield() syscall can be used to forcefully relinquish control of a thread. sleep() doesn't *always* work. Oh, and even then GCC will optimize it out on anything but -O0 it seems.

Comment: Thanks for that. What makes you think a mutex would do what you want though? From my understanding mutex's are just semaphores with a value of 1. Unless there is some special mutex attribute that says yield my thread when releasing the mutex or yield when someone else wants the mutex.. I would think you would have the same issue.

The issue really being that the thread holding the mutex is spending 99% of its time in the mutex and 1% of it's time out, so if it is being randomly scheduled out every millisecond or so, it will probably be in the middle of holding the mutex. =/

Comment: That is true, but pthread_mutex_trylock() will immediately return if it can't lock the mutex. Putting this is a loop, waiting for success, will be inefficient but it will work. If you're synchronizing two threads, mutexes are best because they only have 2 states.

Comment: No, but what I am saying is that the trylock for the guy who just unlocked should always succeed unless he happens to be scheduled out in those "two cycles". You still have the same problem. One thread will basically always own that mutex unless he gets scheduled out very unluckily.

I really feel this is a case of "your doing it wrong" though. No thread should be spending 99% of it's time in a hard loop holding a mutex/semaphore. The code inside of a mutex/semaphore should be short and simple so you dont get deadlocks. :P

Comment: Also, why in the living *hell* would it ever optimize out shed_yield (not saying it doesn't just seems insane to me). The only reason someone is calling that function is to give a hint to the scheduler (something the optimizer should know nothing about). Optimizing that out would be as silly as optimizing out "write" or "sleep" or "lock".

Comment: The simple, and reliable, answer is to use two semaphores.  It will always work on any POSIX system or indeed on any OS that provides semaphore support.  You don't need any mutexes or sleep/yield bodges.

Comment: @HashTag James T. Smith has the correct *depiction* of the why the questioner's example fails, but the wrong suggested solution. Martin James comment above has the correct solution, which I also discovered while independently searching for the semaphore/ping-pong case, and posted a working example of in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

The other answers are correct, I'm just posting code that will run as you desire (on OSX 10.10.3 anyway)

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
sem_t pingsem;

void ping(){
    printf("Ping started\n");
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("ping\n");
        sem_post(&pingsem);
    }
}

void pong(){
    printf("Pong started\n");
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&pingsem);
        printf("pong\n");
        sem_post(&pingsem);
    }
}

int main(){
    sem_destroy(&pingsem);  //make sure the semaphore starts dead
    sem_init(&pingsem, 0, 1);  //initialize semaphore
    pthread_t ping_thread, pong_thread;  //start the threading
    pthread_create(&ping_thread, NULL, ping, (void *)0);
    pthread_create(&pong_thread, NULL, pong, (void *)1);


    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does not work properly at all.  You haven't addressed the fundamental race at all. Further, it doesn't compile at all on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Comment: Compiles for me fine on 10.10.3

Comment: My output is as follows, and nor is it a solution the problem described because I tested it on Linux or Solaris and it didn't fix anything, nor do I see how it would:

Comment: x.c:27:5: warning: 'sem_destroy' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    sem_destroy(&pingsem);  //make sure the semaphore starts dead
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/semaphore.h:53:5: note: 
      'sem_destroy' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int sem_destroy(sem_t *) __deprecated;
    ^
x.c:28:5: warning: 'sem_init' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    sem_init(&pingsem, 0, 1);  //initialize semaphore
    ^

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/semaphore.h:55:5: note: 
      'sem_init' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int sem_init(sem_t *, int, unsigned int) __deprecated;
    ^
x.c:30:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_create' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    pthread_create(&ping_thread, NULL, ping, (void *)0);
    ^
x.c:34:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_exit' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    pthread_exit(NULL)

Comment: uname -a
Darwin imac 14.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Thu Feb 26 19:26:47 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.10.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64